# How to run cron job in different time of a days

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I'm developing CRM project in php,MySQL and HTML. I would like to run my script cron job but i had trouble with run cron job. My problem was run cron job in following time period.

**Monday 10 am**

**Tuesday 9 am**

**Wednesday 11 am**

**Thursday 3 pm**

**Friday 7 pm**

**and Saturday, Sunday cron job don't run.**

Comment: Set multiple jobs..May be 5 in your case..

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: I would like to run cron job in the certain time of period in regular.

Comment: make 5 copies of your file and make 5 jobs according to your time

Comment: setting only multiple jobs for each day, I think it's right way what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. And i got a idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could just cron up your task to run once a hour say every day, then in your code detect the 'day-of-week' and just abort a run not running at the appropriate time for that day.
Yours
Allan